# How to find a key using Mongodb (pymongo)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am having a problem to find a particular value of a key with pymongo. below I printed two document of a collection

```
pprint(list(papers.find().limit(2)))

[{'_id': ObjectId('5fa9a4db76fdd8d66273c643'),
'abstract': '  A fully differential calculation in perturbative quantum '
          'chromodynamics is\n'
          'presented for the production of massive photon pairs at hadron '
          'colliders. All\n'
          'next-to-leading order perturbative contributions from '
          'quark-antiquark,\n'
          'gluon-(anti)quark, and gluon-gluon subprocesses are included, '
          'as well as\n'
          'all-orders resummation of initial-state gluon radiation valid '
          'at\n'
          'next-to-next-to-leading logarithmic accuracy. The region of '
          'phase space is\n'
          'specified in which the calculation is most reliable. Good '
          'agreement is\n'
          'demonstrated with data from the Fermilab Tevatron, and '
          'predictions are made for\n'
          'more detailed tests with CDF and DO data. Predictions are shown '
          'for\n'
          'distributions of diphoton pairs produced at the energy of the '
          'Large Hadron\n'
          'Collider (LHC). Distributions of the diphoton pairs from the '
          'decay of a Higgs\n'
          'boson are contrasted with those produced from QCD processes at '
          'the LHC, showing\n'
          'that enhanced sensitivity to the signal can be obtained with '
          'judicious\n'
          'selection of events.\n',
'authors': "C. Bal\\'azs, E. L. Berger, P. M. Nadolsky, C.-P. Yuan",
'authors_parsed': [['Balázs', 'C.', ''],
                 ['Berger', 'E. L.', ''],
                 ['Nadolsky', 'P. M.', ''],
                 ['Yuan', 'C. -P.', '']],
'categories': 'hep-ph',
'comments': '37 pages, 15 figures; published version',
'doi': '10.1103/PhysRevD.76.013009',
'id': '0704.0001',
'journal-ref': 'Phys.Rev.D76:013009,2007',
'license': None,
'report-no': 'ANL-HEP-PR-07-12',
'submitter': 'Pavel Nadolsky',
'title': 'Calculation of prompt diphoton production cross sections at '
       'Tevatron and\n'
       '  LHC energies',
'update_date': '2008-11-26',
'versions': [{'created': 'Mon, 2 Apr 2007 19:18:42 GMT', 'version': 'v1'},
           {'created': 'Tue, 24 Jul 2007 20:10:27 GMT', 'version': 'v2'}]},
{'_id': ObjectId('5fa9a4db76fdd8d66273c644'),
'abstract': '  We describe a new algorithm, the $(k,\\ell)$-pebble game with '
          'colors, and use\n'
          'it obtain a characterization of the family of '
          '$(k,\\ell)$-sparse graphs and\n'
          'algorithmic solutions to a family of problems concerning tree '
          'decompositions of\n'
          'graphs. Special instances of sparse graphs appear in rigidity '
          'theory and have\n'
          'received increased attention in recent years. In particular, '
          'our colored\n'
          'pebbles generalize and strengthen the previous results of Lee '
          'and Streinu and\n'
          'give a new proof of the Tutte-Nash-Williams characterization of '
          'arboricity. We\n'
          'also present a new decomposition that certifies sparsity based '
          'on the\n'
          '$(k,\\ell)$-pebble game with colors. Our work also exposes '
          'connections between\n'
          'pebble game algorithms and previous sparse graph algorithms by '
          'Gabow, Gabow and\n'
          'Westermann and Hendrickson.\n',
'authors': 'Ileana Streinu and Louis Theran',
'authors_parsed': [['Streinu', 'Ileana', ''], ['Theran', 'Louis', '']],
'categories': 'math.CO cs.CG',
'comments': 'To appear in Graphs and Combinatorics',
'doi': None,
'id': '0704.0002',
'journal-ref': None,
'license': 'http://arxiv.org/licenses/nonexclusive-distrib/1.0/',
'report-no': None,
'submitter': 'Louis Theran',
'title': 'Sparsity-certifying Graph Decompositions',
'update_date': '2008-12-13',
'versions': [{'created': 'Sat, 31 Mar 2007 02:26:18 GMT', 'version': 'v1'},
           {'created': 'Sat, 13 Dec 2008 17:26:00 GMT', 'version': 'v2'}]}]
```

I am trying to get the nombre of articls that are not published by "Damien Chablat".
the articles here are the key title and also we have to use the author key.

I just entred the following command but it's not working:

```
pprint(len(list(papers.find({},{"authors":{$ne: "Damien Chablat"}, '_id':0}))))
```

the error is :

```
pprint(len(list(papers.find({},{"authors":{$ne: "Damien Chablat"}, '_id':0}))))
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

please help me.thanks in advance

Comment: Does [`papers.count_documents({"authors":{"$ne": "Damien Chablat"}})`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents) give the value you are looking for?

Comment: I don't know is it worked or not. Basically, I have executed a command to get the numbers of all the documents of papers and the result is 10000 '''print(len(list(papers.find({}))))''''. and the request you mentioned also gave me the same value  even though we have excluded the authors with the value  "Damien Chablat". So, it's a little bit confusing

Comment: Well, what is `papers.count_documents({"authors": "Damien Chablat"})`?

Comment: papers.count_documents({"authors": "Damien Chablat"})
0    it's a zero.I dont know, anyway thanks for the help

Comment: So, that means there is no document where the value of `"authors"` is exactly `"Damien Chablat"`.  Perhaps you need a different strategy, like using `"$regex"` or split `Damien Chablat"` and compare to `"authors_parsed"`?

Comment: aa ok I'll try that, this is a good idea

Comment: Perhaps look at `list(papers.find({"authors": {"$regex": "Chablat", "$options": "i"}}, {"authors": 1, "authors_parsed": 1}))` to see how his name might appear in the docs.

Comment: it gave me this         [{'authors': "Damien Chablat (IRCCyN), St\\'ephane Caro (IRCCyN), Emilie Bouyer\n  (IRCCyN)",
  'authors_parsed': [['Chablat', 'Damien', '', 'IRCCyN'],
   ['Caro', 'Stéphane', '', 'IRCCyN'],
   ['Bouyer', 'Emilie', '', 'IRCCyN']]},
 {'authors': "Emilie Bouyer (IRCCyN), St\\'ephane Caro (IRCCyN), Damien Chablat\n  (IRCCyN), Jorge Angeles (CIM)",
  'authors_parsed': [['Bouyer', 'Emilie', '', 'IRCCyN'],
   ['Caro', 'Stéphane', '', 'IRCCyN'],
   ['Chablat', 'Damien', '', 'IRCCyN'],
   ['Angeles', 'Jorge', '', 'CIM']]},

Comment: pprint(len(list(papers.find({"authors": {"$regex": "Chablat", "$options": "i"}}, {"authors": 1,"authors_parsed": 1,"_id":0})))))    now with regex  i applied the len to the list and it gave me  32. so now I have to apply the $ne  to see the opposite result.

Comment: Looks like his full name is always used, but I don't know if you can depend on that.  For the current collection, perhaps `papers.count_documents({"authors": {"$not": {"$regex": "Damien Chablat"}}})` is good enough.

Comment: I think it worked. it gave me 9968   this is logic I think. and thanks a lot you are a live saver, I'll apreciate it

Comment: Write an answer below and I'll upvote it.

Comment: papers.count_documents({"authors": {"$not": {"$regex": "Damien Chablat"}}})
9968

Comment: Is that what you asked for?

Comment: I actually meant you to complete a _"Your Answer"_ below.  You can answer your own question.  Just show the code and explain why it gives you the answer you want.

Comment: aa ok I get it  thanks

Answer (score 1):

This first request is for searching a string using regex to find a value("Damien Chablat")

```
 pprint(len(list(papers.find({"authors": {"$regex": "Damien Chablat"}}, 
 {"authors": 1,"authors_parsed": 1,"_id":0}))))
```

this gave 32 a the number of article published by damien

But we need to find out the articls that are not published by Damien so as follow:

```
 papers.count_documents({"authors": {"$not": {"$regex": "Damien 
 Chablat"}}})
```

this one gave 9968